# Add subcategories posts to the counts column at the admin's categories list

Tags: categories, terms, count

By default the `Count` column shows the number of category's own posts only. Instead, I want to see the total number of records taking into account posts in child categories.

[image: screenshot]

I know that [the `get_terms` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) has the `pad_counts` parameter:

> Whether to pad the quantity of a term's children in the quantity of each term's "count" object variable. Default false.

So I suppose that I can change the same parameter for some query using some hook. But how to find them? Is my guess correct?

Comment: So in the screenshot above you expect the parent category count to be 2 not 0?

Comment: Yes, I would like that.

Comment: Have you considered removing that column and adding your own Count column in?

Comment: I can do it. But I hope I can correct someone else's work instead of redoing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change an array of `get_terms()` arguments with two filters:

1. [`get_terms_defaults`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms_defaults/) filters the terms query ***default*** arguments;
2. [`get_terms_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms_args/) filters the terms query ***passed*** arguments.

For example, this code will change the default value for the `pad_counts` parameter for all queries related to categories and called from the administrative part of the site.

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_defaults', 'custom_get_terms_defaults', 10, 2 );
function custom_get_terms_defaults( $defaults, $taxonomies ) {
  if ( is_admin() && in_array( 'category', $taxonomies ) ) {
    $defaults['pad_counts'] = true;
  }
  return $defaults;
}
```

[image: result]